# Backup GPO by displayname and not ID - powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to backup GPOs using their names instead of their ID's.  Currently I have:

```
$GPO_Temp_Backup = get-gpo -all -domain $domain

Foreach ($GPO in $GPO_Temp_Backup) {

$GPOBackup = Backup GPO -name $GPO.DisplayName -path ($Current_Drive + $GPO_Backup_Location) -Domain $domain;
write-host $GPO.DisplayName
}
```

I can post any other parts of the script as needed but most of the missing variable values shouldn't matter for the question.  As of now, it still backs up the GPO's as their ID's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I decided to change the code a bit so I could debug what was going on.  I added `writeout $GPOBackup` and `writeout $GPO`.  Interestingly this is similar to what I saw.  (Example taken from Microsoft page)

`writeout $GPOBackup` provided me with:

```
C:\PS>
Backup-Gpo -Name TestGPO -Path C:\GpoBackups -Comment "Weekly Backup"
DisplayName     : TestGPO
GpoId           : 35c12ab3-956c-45d5-973b-46b17d225f47
Id              : 2b509d4e-40f5-4337-82f7-458584555d0c
BackupDirectory : C:\GpoBackups
CreationTime    : 2/25/2009 8:48:19 PM
DomainName      : contoso.com
Comment         : Weekly Backup
```

`writeout $GPO` provided me with:

```
Id: 35c12ab3-956c-45d5-973b-46b17d225f47
DisplayName : TestGPO
Path: cn={35c12ab3-956c-45d5-973b-46b17d225f47}
```

As you can see in the first output there is a GpoId and an Id.  The output of the second command suddenly changes the Id to what was originally the GpoID.  When the `backup-gpo` command saves the GPO it saves it using the Id that you receive from the first block of code.  The Id then changes to what is the `GpoId`.  I have no clue as to why this happens but at any rate, the fix for me was simple once I figured this out.  The follow code allowed me to `backup GPOs` as `DisplayName`

```
Foreach ($GPO in $GPO_Temp_Backup) {
$GPOBackup = Backup-GPO -name $GPO.DisplayName -path ($Current_drive + $GPO_Backup_Location + "\" + "{" + $GPO.Id + "}") -domain $domain
rename-item -path ($Current_drive + $GPO_Backup_Location + "\" + "{" + $GPOBackup.Id + "}") -newname $GPO.DisplayName
}
$oldfilename = ($Current_drive + $GPO_Backup_Location + "\" + "{" + $GPOBackup.Id + "}")
write $oldfilename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script I wrote to backup all GPOs in the domain. This takes advantage of the manifest.xml file created by Backup-GPO to get around the Id issue:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter()]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
    [string]$Path = 'C:\GroupPolicy'
)

Get-GPO -All | Backup-GPO -Path $Path -Comment ('Backup taken: {0}' -f (Get-Date -Format G))
[xml]$manifest = Get-Content (Join-Path $Path 'manifest.xml')
foreach ($gpBackup in $manifest.Backups.BackupInst) {
    Rename-Item -Path (Join-Path $Path $gpBackup.Id.InnerText) -NewName ($gpBackup.GPODisplayName.InnerText -replace '[:\\/]','')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just use the $gpobackup.id to get the guid, convert it to folder path and then simply use rename. Example:

```
$GPOBackup = Backup-GPO -name $GPO.DisplayName -path ($Current_Drive + $GPO_Backup_Location) -Domain $domain;
$guidpath = $($Current_Drive + $GPO_Backup_Location + '{' + $x.id.tostring() + '}' )
$newpath = $($Current_Drive + $GPO_Backup_Location + $GPOBackup.DisplayName)
rename-item -Path $guidpath -newname $newpath
```